# Joomla mod_login vs com_user

Tags: authentication, joomla, components

I'm having a very weird issue with user logins.

I'm building a site where all the content/menus are only available after you login.

I made a 'login' through the Modules and assign it the "userlogin" position.

Now when I go to the home page or any page, the login box comes up, but there's also a second login form. It seems to be coming from com_user.

This com_user login form doesn't work. I can't login using any credentials. If it was working I can simply remove my login module.

Is there a way I can either:

- get com_user to work with normal user logins

or

- disable this and so I can only see the Module login.

I can hide it from CSS, but I want to know where it's coming from.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the menu link which you have created should be public.

If these are not public then whenever user clicks it, he/she will be asked for login. Thats why the second login option is coming up.